# java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I am inserting a table's data into another table with dynamic partitions in hive.

```
insert into table x partition(c) select a,b,c from y distribute by c;
```

I get this error while inserting data from one of the input tables.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
```

Is this problem with data? or problem while saving the data blocks in datanode? How do I fix this?

Thanks